# Set Device-Specific font in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel, xcode8

i want to set Device-Specific font of UILabel and UIButton using storyboard.

Any one can help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set Label Font Size based on Device using Storyboard. To make it you have follow some steps like below.

First go to the Attributes Inspector panel in storyboard.

[image]

Click on this + Symbol of Font Property.

[image]

Now set the variations for other devices, Like Compact Width and Compact Height or etc. Set it based on your requirements.

[image]

Finally, it will look like,

[image]

you can set this property multiple times as per your device specifications like iPhone or iPad etc. You need to define only variations so it will automatic set font size and fonts also.

Hope you get it.